# How to stop propagation of events attached on other elements in DOM on focusout (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I implemented validation on `focusout`, i.e. whenever user focuses out of text fields code validates, alerts, highlights and focuses back on text field so that user can delete some characters. Check Fiddle below as alert is not working in code snippet-

http://jsfiddle.net/tpro5ago/

It works fine on browser. Problem is if I tap on any other button with event attached, it fires that event as well. In this case it alerts 'yay' and as well as 'maximum character limit reached' when I type more than 35 characters in textbox and click on 'I will stop you from validating on mobile'. I want to write my code in such a way that if `maxlength` is reached no other event fires without using jQuery `off()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".limit-thirtyfive").on("focusout", function(event) {
    _this = $(this);
    if (event.keyCode != 8 || event.keyCode != 46) {
      console.log('KEYCODE BEFORE---------' + event.keyCode);
      if (_this.val().length > 35) {
        //$(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 35));
        console.log('KEYCODE AFTER---------' + event.keyCode);
        _this.css('background', '#F6CECE');
        _this.focus();
        alert('Maximum character limit reached');
        event.preventDefault();
        return 0;
      } else if (_this.val().length <= 35) {
        _this.css('background', 'transparent none');
      }
    }
  });
  $('#btnAlert').click(function() {
    alert('yay');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" class="limit-thirtyfive"></input>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" class="limit-thirtyfive"></input>
<input type="text" id="textbox3" class="limit-thirtyfive"></input>

<button id="btnAlert">I will stop you from validating on mobile</button>
```